# Tackle low FPS for correlation code to compute shift in Image

Tags: c++, image-processing, correlation, cross-correlation

I am trying to track an object using correlation. I am finding a smaller patch in a larger image, frame by frame. For this, I am finding the shift in the patch, and where correlation is maximum, update the patch with a new patch.

My code is:

```
cv::Mat im_float_2,imagePart_out;
cv::Mat im_floatBig;
cv::Scalar im1_Mean, im1_Std, im2_Mean, im2_Std;

double covar, correl;
int n_pixels;

void computeShift()
{
    int maxRow=0, maxCol=0, TX, TY;
    double GMAX=0;
    Mat image_window = Mat::zeros(imagePart.rows, imagePart.cols, CV_32F);

    imagePart.convertTo(im_float_2, CV_32F);
    imageBig.convertTo(im_floatBig,CV_32F);

    for(maxRow=0; maxRow<=imageBig.rows-image_window.rows;maxRow++)
    {
        for(maxCol=0; maxCol<imageBig.cols-image_window.cols;maxCol++)
        {

            image_window = im_floatBig( cv::Rect( maxCol, maxRow, 
            image_window.cols, image_window.rows ) );

            n_pixels = image_window.rows * image_window.cols;

            // Compute mean and standard deviation of both images

            meanStdDev(image_window, im1_Mean, im1_Std);
            meanStdDev(im_float_2, im2_Mean, im2_Std);

            // Compute covariance and correlation coefficient
            covar = (image_window - im1_Mean).dot(im_float_2 - im2_Mean) / n_pixels;

            correl = covar / (im1_Std[0] * im2_Std[0]);
            if (correl > GMAX)
            {
            GMAX = correl; TX = maxRow; TY=maxCol;
            image_window.convertTo(imagePart, CV_8UC1);
            }
        }
    }

            cvtColor(imagePart, imagePart_out, CV_GRAY2BGR);
            printf("\nComputed shift: [%d, %d] MAX: %f\n", TX, TY,GMAX);                

}
```

But when executing this I am getting very low FPS(1-2) even for small video size (Frame size-`262x240`, Patch size- `25x25`).

Is there any way to achieve higher FPS. I am also looking in the direction of phase correlation, but not sure how to go about it from here. Can converting it to frequency domain will help?

For now, I want to optimize the above code for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will likely gain from using the FFT. Simply pad `im_float_2` to the size of `im_floatBig`. Multiplying in the Fourier domain after taking the complex conjugate of one of the transforms leads to the cross-correlation, which is not the same as your `correl` value (there is no division by the standard deviations happening). But I don't think you actually need to normalize by the standard deviations to get a good template matching. The cross-correlation works really well by itself. The location of maximum in the result can be translated to a displacement of the template w.r.t. the image.

The steps for cross-correlation through the FFT are:

1. Pad the template (floating image) to the size of the other image (with zeros).
2. Compute the FFT of both.
3. Flip the sign of the imaginary component of one of the results (complex conjugate).
4. Multiply the two.
5. Compute the IFFT of the result.
6. Find the location of the pixel with the largest value.

The location of this pixel indicates the translation of the padded template w.r.t. the other image. If they best match without translation, the max pixel will be at (x,y)=(0,0). If it is at (1,0) it indicates a one-pixel shift along x. What the direction is depends on which of the two you computed the complex conjugate for. Note that this result is periodic, a one-pixel shift in the opposite direction is indicated by the max pixel being on the right edge of the image. Simply experiment a bit to determine how to translate the location to a shift of your template.

Regarding your code:

1. `meanStdDev(im_float_2, im2_Mean, im2_Std);` is computed in the loop, even though `im_float_2` doesn't change.
2. But you could get away with not normalizing by it anyway, since you're just looking for the maximum correlation, and dividing all values in your search by the same number doesn't change which one is the largest. The same applies to the division by `n_pixels`.
3. Move `image_window.convertTo(imagePart, CV_8UC1)` outside the loop. It is likely that  you update your current max many times before you finally find the actual max. There is no point in converting so many sub-windows to `CV_U8`, if you only end up using the last one. Inside the loop you update the (x,y) coordinates of the max. Cast the final location only.
4. You probably don't need to search the whole image for your template. It is likely that the object moves only a relatively small amount. You should look only in a small region around the previous known location. This concept is applicable to the FFT method as well: crop out a region of your big image, and pad your template to that size. A smaller FFT is cheaper to compute.
5. OpenCV stores images row-wise. Put the loop over the rows as the inner loop to optimize your cache usage.

Comment: I incorporated your point 1 and 2 and there was some improvement. Regarding point 3, since I am updating it in each cycle so that I don't lose track, I am simply converting as well as renaming and thus updating it to imagePart. Also, I am showing it on screen and writing to videoWriter as well.
4th point- How to incorporate it in the spatial domain?

Comment: Regarding FFT, I will get a matrix of FFT for each cycle which gives many values(FFT of two images), where as in spatial domain corellation of two image gives me only one coefficient. I just have to traverse the patch and find where the correlation coeff is maximum and update the patch.
I tried finding it by FFT. I first found max of two patch(say `localMax`) and then traverse the patch and udating my `globalMax` whenver `localMax` is greater. But it doesn't give me correct results.

Comment: @A.k. Are you saying you update the display *within* your loop? I'll bet that is 95% of your execution time right there... Don't do anything unnecessary within the loop if you want to speed it up. Converting the patch to `CV_U8` is not for free, move it out of the loop. Reducing the search radius will also be a big increase in speed.

Comment: @A.k. I have updated the post to include a short description of computing the cross-correlation through the FFT. I do recommend that you Google a bit, there are tons of tutorials on the topic online. I have also added a 5th point on how to speed up your code.

Comment: How to show images in real time without updating it inside the loop?

Comment: In FFT method, since I am calculating FFT of a small image patch (which contains my object) and running windows from a bigger frame(current frame of video) of patch size, I have to do a no. of FFT operations for a single frame. Each FFT operation will give me a max value for that area and I have to find a `globalmax` to calculate the location of the patch in the frame. Will `globalmax` be maximum for the patch which contains my image? Because when I tried this approach, I couldn't get the correct result. I am already following the steps mentioned by you.

Comment: @A.k.: showing images in real time would be showing each frame once, no? Updating the display for each frame many times is wasteful. Compute the shift without displaying anything, then display the result at the end. Regarding  the FFT: no, you compute the FFT once for each frame. You make the small patch larger by adding zeros, so it's the size of the full frame. Then you compute the FFT for both, multiply and compute the inverse FFT. Within that result you look for the max and that gives you the location of the best match of your small patch within the frame.

Comment: Right!  I got what you're saying. I moved the update window outside the loop. Some improvement is there. But not as much as 95% as you mentioned earlier. I hope I am doing it right.
I am just gonna try the FFT method and after that, I will accept this as the answer, as it helped me.

Comment: Should I pad zeros all around the patch or just right and bottom of the patch?

Comment: @A.k.: That doesn't matter. It will affect the relationship between the location of the maximum and the actual translation of the patch, but you'll need to figure out this relationship anyway.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. And regarding FFT correlation I have asked another question. Please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52778061/phase-correlation-for-template-matching